# comparing money in sql server with decimal in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have some fields in db with type money and in C# I have used decimal for them. I am comparing values in C# c ode like this:

```
public static string CompareValues(DbPropertyValues currentValues, DbPropertyValues DbValues)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            foreach (var currentPropertyName in currentValues.PropertyNames)
            {
                foreach (var DBPropertyName in DbValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    if (DBPropertyName == "PropertyCreditLimit" || DBPropertyName == "PropertyCreditLimit" || DBPropertyName == "PropertyCreditLimit" || DBPropertyName == "PropertyCreditLimit" || DBPropertyName == "PropertyCreditLimit")


                    if ((currentPropertyName == DBPropertyName))
                    {
                        if (( currentValues[currentPropertyName] != null && DbValues != null) &&  (currentValues[currentPropertyName].ToString() != DbValues[DBPropertyName].ToString()))
                        {
                            result += string.Format("Property{0}, {1} =  {2}, {3} <br />", currentPropertyName, DbValues[DBPropertyName], currentValues[currentPropertyName], DBPropertyName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

but it is not matching due to number of zeros/precision:

```
PropertyDateFirstReported, 3/8/2008 1:15:36 AM = 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, DateFirstReported 
PropertyCreditLimit, 564000.0000 = 564000.00, CreditLimit 
PropertyBalance, 45.0000 = 45.00, Balance 
PropertyMinimumInstallment, 0.0000 = 0.00, MinimumInstallment 
PropertyTerm, = Term1, Term 
PropertyPurpose, a = a1, Purpose 
PropertyCollateralValue, 0.0000 = 0.00, CollateralValue 
PropertyAccountUniqueID, 3767 = 0, AccountUniqueID 
PropertyPayment, 564000.0000 = 564000.00, Payment
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do a string comparison, use the 'f2' formatter to guarantee 2 decimal places. Otherwise, just cast the DB value to a `(decimal)`.

Probably something like this:

```
bool isEqual = false;
if ( currentValues[currentPropertyName] != null && DbValues != null) {
 if (currentValues[currentPropertyName] is decimal && DbValues[DBPropertyName] is decimal) {
   isEqual = (Decimal)currentValues[currentPropertyName] == (Decimal)DbValues[DBPropertyName];
} else {
   isEqual = currentValues[currentPropertyName].ToString() == DbValues[DBPropertyName].ToString();
}
```

You can add additional else clauses if you find other data types where `ToString()` doesn't give you the correct value for comparison. Or you can add them to avoid to `ToString()` call at all.

Comment: How I change my function. can you please suggest ?

Comment: I updated my code to test for data type before testing for equality

Comment: @ drdwilcox It works but partially. Now If I change date it doesn't show in this comparison. It only works for decimals. How to change this ?

Comment: Of course it only works for Decimals. If you want to test other types, you will need more if statements, each testing the type. I have modified my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (currentValues[currentPropertyName].ToString() != DbValues[DBPropertyName].ToString()
```

You are currently comparing them *as strings* which explains why there is no match - you have to compare the values directly instead.

Comment: currentValues[currentPropertyName]  returns null so I need to convert to string.

Comment: Test for that first, equality with null is always false anyway.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow. Exactly null != anything ever. So if the value you are testing is null, result is false no casting, "ToStringing" etc required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to compare them as strings, you'll need them in the same format, e.g

.ToString("F02",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Why don't you convert the Money to Decimal on read / write from the DB, you are going to be all over the place with this.

Comment: some of these are dates. is that any issue ?

Comment: Yes, that's an issue. You might want to edit or ask your question again. You seem to have coded yourself into a deep hole, and you want us to advise you on rescue equipment.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!object.Equals(currentValues[currentPropertyName], DbValues[DBPropertyName]))
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

Remarks:
object.Equals(null, null) is considered true

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert to strings to compare decimal amounts; nulls, padding, formats, localization, significant digits, decimal places, can all change at runtime. You're planting land mines in your code. Do this.

```
decimal? d1 = currentValues[currentPropertyName] as Nullable<decimal>;
decimal? d2 = (DbValues == null)? null : DbValues[DBPropertyName] as Nullable<decimal>;
if (d1 == d2)
    ...;
```

Comment: You told us your field are "type money". If that is false you have to fix your question. If you have fields of different type you need a different comparison for each data type. In fact, you should store each data type in a separate field. Trying to store and compare different data types in the same field is another land mine in your code.